# ArcGIS Desktop: Dynamic label of layer attribute (Sum of line length)

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.6, dynamic-text

I'm trying to put a dynamic text label beside a legend entry for a road layer that has the length of the road dataset in ArcMap Desktop (10.6).

I usually work in QGIS so I'm not familiar with the proper way to do this in ArcMap. In QGIS you could create a label and use this code:

`[%to_int(aggregate('my_layer','sum',"FEATURE_LENGTH")/1000)%]`

However, I'm not sure what the equivalent would be in ArcMap and can't seem to dig up an answer with Google. Does anyone know how to do this?